Norm inequality for positive definite inverse $\|D(A+B)^{-1}C\| \leq \|DA^{-1}C\|$
Let $A$ be an invertible and positive definite symmetric matrix, and $B$ a positive semi-definite symmetric matrix. I want to show that
$$\|D(A+B)^{-1}C\| \leq \|DA^{-1}C\|$$
for general matrices $D$ and $C$, and the spectral norm.

I am able to prove the following norm inequality: $$\|(A+B)^{-1}C\| \leq ||A^{-1}C||$$
The idea is to write $\|(A+B)^{-1}C\| = \|(A+B)^{-1}AA^{-1}C\| \leq \|(A+B)^{-1}A\| \|A^{-1}C\|$ so it suffices to show that $\|(A+B)^{-1}A\|\leq 1$.
Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue for $(A+B)^{-1}A$ with eigenvector $x$. Then,
$$Ax = \lambda (A+B)x$$
and after premultiplying by $x'$ and rearranging
$\lambda =  \frac{x'Ax}{x'Ax + x'Bx} \leq 1$, since $x'Ax$ and $x'Bx$ are non-negative.
However, this proof technique does not work for showing $\|D(A+B)^{-1}C\| \leq \|DA^{-1}C\|$.
Another idea is to use Loewner theory:
Since $A+B\geq A$ in the Loewner sense, then $A^{-1}\geq (A+B)^{-1}$, and so $C'A^{-1}C\geq C'(A+B)^{-1}C$ but this only allows us to prove that $\|C'A^{-1}C\|\geq \|C'(A+B)^{-1}C\|$.

What's the norm in this case?

@DamianPavlyshyn The spectral norm

This is not true. Hint: consider C and D diagonal with single non-zero entry.

You cannot prove it because the inequality $\|(A+B)^{-1}C\|\le\|A^{-1}C\|$ is already false. It is false because $\|A^{-1}C\|^2=\rho(C^\ast A^{-2}C)$, but matrix square is not operator monotone on the set of all positive definite matrices. Here is a random counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{8&6\\ 6&4},
\quad B=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1},
\quad C=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 0&0}.
$$
Numerically we have $\|(A+B)^{-1}C\|=2.7613>2.5495=\|A^{-1}C\|$.
Your proof is wrong for two reasons. First, the step $\lambda\le1$ is irrelevant: on the unit sphere, $\|(A+B)^{-1}Ax\|$ in general is maximised by a singular vector of $(A+B)^{-1}A$, not by an eigenvector. Second, $\|(A+B)^{-1}A\|$ is actually not bounded above (proof). You cannot prove that it is $\le1$.
